# ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread on Windows on Python 3.8 with Django 3.0.2 or Flask 2.0.0

Tags: python, flask, asgi

When I run my Django Web application with Apache2.4.41 + Python 3.8.1 + Django 3.0.2 + MySQL 8.0.19 on Windows 10 Professional version it throws Value Error at /. set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread.

This issue was a result of regression in Python 3.8 and was fixed in November in later builds of Python. For more details - https://bugs.python.org/issue38563.

Stacktrace of the error is as follows -

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/

Django Version: 3.0.2
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['Analysis.apps.AnalysisConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize']


Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\IndianMarketAnalysis\ISMA\Analysis\views.py", line 8, in home
    date_list = dict(d.date_list())
  File "F:\IndianMarketAnalysis\ISMA\Analysis\models.py", line 7, in date_list
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 19, in inner
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "c:\python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 636, in get_event_loop
    self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
  File "c:\python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in new_event_loop
    return self._loop_factory()
  File "c:\python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 310, in __init__
    super().__init__(proactor)
  File "c:\python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 632, in __init__
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(self._csock.fileno())

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
```

Further, this application works very well on local Development Environment using - python manage.py runserver.

Please suggest the next steps to move forward.

---

The same issue happens on Flask 2.0.0 (`pip install --pre flask`):

```
@app.get('/')
async def say_hello():
    return {'message': 'Hello!'}
```

```
> flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1454, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1452, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\app.py", line 318, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](*req.view_args.values())
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 781, in outer
    return async_to_sync(inner)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 203, in __call__
    loop_future.result()
  File "C:\Users\greyli\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\greyli\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.0\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\greyli\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.0\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\users\greyli\...\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 256, in _run_event_loop
    loop.close()
  File "C:\Users\greyli\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 679, in 
close
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(-1)
ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
```

Comment: This is a bug by using python 3 in windows, I tested it. The bug remains on windows 10 with python 3.10.0 but by using linux ubuntu with python 3.10.0 the bug dissapears

Answer (score 7):

I have exactly the same bug. I opened the [issue](https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/143).

If you want to stay on the current Python version I have found the temporal solution which is to add following lines to `asgiref\__init__.py` (as it was suggested in [issue](https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/143)):

```
if sys.platform == "win32" and sys.version_info >= (3, 8, 0):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: Some More Updates - This bug can be reproduced using the following combinations as well - Python3.8.2rc2 + Django 3.0.3 + Apache 2.4.41

Answer (score 3):

Not only Django, but you will also meet this error with Flask since Flask 2.0.0 uses asgiref to support `async`.

This bug was fixed in Python 3.9, so there are two solutions:

- Upgrade to Python 3.9
- Add the temp fix as follows (based on [Dennis B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371969/5511849)) to your entry script, for example, Flask's `app.py` or Django's `manager.py`:

```
# top of the file
import sys, asyncio

if sys.platform == "win32" and (3, 8, 0) <= sys.version_info < (3, 9, 0):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: I had the same bug with Python 3.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

I had to downgrade to Python 3.7 and then it started to work perfectly.

Comment: I had been experiencing the error message in topic with Django/Apache and I tried different versions of Python 3.8 to no avail.  However, rolling back to Python 3.7 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

upgraded to python 3.8.2 , worked fine on my windows server.

release notes
https://docs.python.org/release/3.8.2/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-2-final

issue bpo-34679: fixed 
 asynci.ProactorEventLoop.close() now only calls signal.set_wakeup_fd() in the main thread.

Comment: I wish I could say the same. I'm having this issue on Windows Server with 3.8.2, but my local development is in 3.8.1. Local development works fine; server doesn't.

Comment: I had a similar problem with `pweave`. Upgrading to Python 3.8.10 on Windows solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after creating conda virtual env, in which I run the following installations:

- conda create --name tfgpu220 python==3.8
- conda activate tfgpu220
- pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
- pip install spyder (next thin you do you set up the spyder env interpreter)
- spyder (to launch spyder from the created conda env)
- go to Tools->Preferences-> Python interpreter -> and browse to the python.exe inside the created conda virtual env.
  I end up facing this issue with spyder crasging with => ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread on Windows...

So I gave it a retry and created a new conda env, this time with cosidering the conda message to update my conda version:

- conda update -n base -c defaults conda
  and taking the following advice:

"If you install pip packages maybe creating an enviroment only using pip packages could help. So by running from an Anaconda prompt something like:

- conda create -n pip-tf220 -c conda-forge python=3.8
- conda activate pip-tf220
- pip install 
  "

I followed the same instructions as above, launched spyder, set the python interpreter to the new python.exe of the new conda env.
That is how I resolved the crashing issue.