# How to stream OpenCV output video to Plotly Dash App?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, plotly-dash

I am working on a Dash App which is similar to [this app](https://dash.gallery/bball-video-analysis/). I am also using OpenCV for pose detection on youtube videos.

As you can see on the app which I linked above, after clicking on "Run Model" the model's output is displayed below, I am not sure if the output format is gif or any other. I can't figure out how to display my output video in a similar way on my Dash App.

If anyone knows how this can be done please guide me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this post answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856716/2428887

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer from that thread helped a lot, can you guide me on how to 
 modify the clientside callback function to also take an additional input from a dash component for video path?